# Duplicity --> Show progress but don't log progress

Tags: duplicity

With Duplicity, I want to see progress (--progress) which is fine.  I also want a log but Duplicity will log EVERY progress entry.   The log file then becomes ENORMOUS but is all progress bar entries............   What I really want in a log file is at the end, the report of errors or warnings, I need to do without all that is preceding that.

The -ve -vw options seem to suppress both what is displayed and what is logged so I'm seemingly unable to see backup progress while creating a log that omits progress...........

Answer (score 0):

sorry, that is not possible. reporting progress write/deletes output written which is unsupported for piping/log file writing.

as implemented now, you may either pipe to/write a log file or use progress but have it put out to shell only if you do not want the progress cluttering your log file.